# Changing Label's Text in Static Context

Tags: c#, static, label, this

I'm creating a Help Section in my program and I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible while using the coding knowledge I have. I have set up a method to where if I type `Help.whichHelp(some_int_here);` as follows. All of this code is in one file, `Help.cs`. But the labels are not changing, even when no other code but this should be changing the labels.

```
public static void whichHelp(int index)
    {
        int allowedCount = 0;
        foreach (string namesX in HWLib.Variables.helpDir)
        {
            allowedCount++;
        }
        if (index > allowedCount)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Index " + index + " does not exist!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (index == 0) Login();
        }
    }
```

Here is the "login" method referenced above if index is 0.

```
public static void Login()
    {
        Help.getContent("Log In", "In order to use this program,  you need to be able to log in. " +
            "This is so we can track how many users we have. It also provides many user benefits to you! " +
            "\n\n To login, use the username and password provided when you signed up on the website. " +
            "if you did not signup,  you should do so by clicking the \"SignUp\" button on the login screen.");
    }
```

And here is the method for getting the content

```
static void getContent(String header, String body)
    {
        if (header == null || body == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading contents of program");
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            //Since "this" isn't valid for an identifier in static context
            Help thisI = new Help();
            thisI.headerLabel.Text = header;
            thisI.bodyLabel.Text = body;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: Without any more information, I think the answer is "don't use a static in this case"

Comment: Sorry I got caught up in the post :)

Comment: I don't know what else to use but static because the first block of code is referenced from another file

Answer (score 0):

The labels will never change because of this

```
Help thisI = new Help();
thisI.headerLabel.Text = header;
thisI.bodyLabel.Text = body;
```

These are local variables which only exists in the static method.

What about passing the Help object into the method?

```
static void getContent(String header, String body, Help thisI)
```

This part of the code could be change from

```
int allowedCount = 0;
foreach (string namesX in HWLib.Variables.helpDir)
{
    allowedCount++;
}
if (index > allowedCount)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Index " + index + " does not exist!");
}
```

to something like this

```
if (index > HWLib.Variables.helpDir.Count() )
{
    MessageBox.Show("Index " + index + " does not exist!");
}
```

Comment: I won't have VS access until Monday so I'll try it then